# How to close a ipynb file (started using %run ./code.ipynb command) from another notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running too many ipynb files together so i need to close each one after finishing running

I ran it using the code

```
%run ./code1.ipynb
%run ./code2.ipynb
%run ./code3.ipynb
```

I need to close it after each one.